# Perl: check existence of file with wildcard

Tags: perl

I am trying to use -e to check existence of a file, $name is any input specified by user, `"_file_"` is something fixed, and * could be anything possible. Currently it is not able to detect the file.

```
if (-e $name."_file_*.txt)
{
   do something;
}
```

Comment: you can't have a wild card, it has to be a specific file name

Comment: You should ask yourself following question: _Is `$name."_file_*.txt"` represents one file or many?_ `-e` check only for one particular file nothing else. [documentation](https://www.perltutorial.org/perl-file-test-operators/)

Comment: yes i know $name."_file_*.txt" refer to one file name in this case. But I wanted to search the existence of any file that match the condition.

Comment: Are you going to open the file after checking if it exists?

Comment: nope, just wanted to check the existence

Comment: Then use `for my $file (glob("${name}_file_*.txt")) { if( -e $file ) { say $file; } }` -- prints all filenames matching **pattern**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use [`glob()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) for that?

```perl
if (my @files = glob("\Q$name\E_file_*.txt")) {
  # do something
}
```

Comment: @ikegami it's kind of freaky when i see your name [here](https://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=468052) lol .. thanks!

Comment: Considering the number of Perl questions I've answered, not really :) `"\Q...\E"` is short for `quotemeta("...")`, which escapes non-word characters with a slash (after interpolation). So if `$name` was `foo bar`, this will result in `glob("foo\\ bar_file_*.txt")` rather than the incorrect `glob("foo bar_file_*.txt")`

Comment: Don't call `glob` in scalar context; you'll get some weird behaviour if you execute that line again (e.g. if it's in a loop or a sub).  You could use `if ( my @files = glob(...) ) { ... }`

Comment: @ikegami you mean when it reaches the end it would return `undef`? i suppose that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the way I could find the existing files with the particular name:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;

my $name = "Test";
my $curdir = getcwd();
my @txtfiles = glob "$curdir/*.txt";
foreach my $txtfile (@txtfiles)
{
    if($txtfile=~m/$name\_file\_(.*?)\.txt/)
    {
        print "Ok...\n";    
    }
    else {  next;  }
}
```

Comment: Why not `my @files = glob("$curdir/${name}_file_*.txt");`? Or even simply `say for glob("$curdir/${name}_file_*.txt");`.

Comment: Yes. There is a way to check

Comment: as you looking for files in `$curdir` it is excessive and can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use File::Find module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

# this takes the function a reference and will be executed for each file in the directory.
find({ wanted => \&process, follow => 1 }, '/dir/to/search' );

sub process {
  my $filename = $_; 
  my $filepath = $File::Find::name;
  if( $filename=~m/$name\_file\_(.*?)\.txt/ ){
    # file exists and do further processing
  } else {
    # file does not exists
  }
}
```